How could I fix this issue where the player does not move in the correct direction?
I am trying to create a Unity movement c# script with the new input system. I encountered an issue where the player does not move in the direction I am looking at. The system also uses Cinemachine for the third person and combat cameras. Everything else functions correctly. Here is a video as well to visually show my issue.
SCRIPT:
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DeviceControls controls;

    [Header("Objects")]
    public GameObject thirdPersonCam;
    public GameObject combatCam;

    [Header("Camera")]
    public CameraStyle currentStyle;
    public Transform orientation;
    public Transform player;
    public Transform playerObj;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Transform combatLookAt;

    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed;
    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;
    Vector3 moveDirection;

    [Header("Grounded")]
    public float playerHeight;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    bool grounded;
    public float groundDrag;

    [Header("Jumping")]
    public float jumpForce;
    public float jumpCooldown;
    public float airMultiplier;
    bool readyToJump;

    public enum CameraStyle
    {
        Basic,
        Combat
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new DeviceControls();
        controls.Gameplay.Jump.performed += ctx => { Jump(); };
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
        readyToJump = true;
        AimCancel();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 viewDir = player.position - new Vector3(transform.position.x, player.position.y, transform.position.z);
        orientation.forward = viewDir.normalized;

        grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);
        if (grounded) rb.drag = groundDrag;
        else rb.drag = 0;

        MyInput();
        SpeedControl();

        if (currentStyle == CameraStyle.Basic)
        {
            moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;
            if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero) playerObj.forward = Vector3.Slerp(playerObj.forward, moveDirection.normalized, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
        else if (currentStyle == CameraStyle.Combat)
        {
            Vector3 dirToCombatLookAt = combatLookAt.position - new Vector3(transform.position.x, player.position.y, transform.position.z);
            orientation.forward = dirToCombatLookAt.normalized;
            playerObj.forward = dirToCombatLookAt.normalized;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (grounded) rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
        else if (!grounded) rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * airMultiplier, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    private void SpeedControl()
    {
        Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);
        if (flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
        {
            Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        if (readyToJump && grounded)
        {
            readyToJump = false;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
        }
        else return;
    }

    private void ResetJump()
    {
        readyToJump = true;
    }

    private void SwitchCameraStyle(CameraStyle newStyle)
    {
        thirdPersonCam.SetActive(false);
        combatCam.SetActive(false);

        if (newStyle == CameraStyle.Basic) thirdPersonCam.SetActive(true);
        if (newStyle == CameraStyle.Combat) combatCam.SetActive(true);

        currentStyle = newStyle;
    }

    private void AimStart()
    {
        SwitchCameraStyle(CameraStyle.Combat);
    }

    private void AimCancel()
    {
        SwitchCameraStyle(CameraStyle.Basic);
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
}

I have tried to modify some of the options in my Update() function but me tweaking with values did not affect the result.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
